# setState doesnot change again once its set

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am using Axios to post data to the server everything is working just fine but I wanted to show error message if email is already exists using a state hook but state does not change once its set can anyone help me what i am doing wrong

```
const [serverError, setServerError] = useState(false);
  const handleRegister = async ({ name, email, password }) => {
    const userdata = { name, email, password };
    const res = await apiUrl.post("/users", userdata);
    if (!res.statusText === "OK") return setServerError(true);
    setServerError(false);
    console.log(serverError);
    console.log(res.data);
    localStorage.setItem("token", res.headers["x-auth-token"]);
  };
```

Comment: It's better to incorporate some punctuations for better readability.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `!=` operator to check for inequality.

```
if (res.statusText != "OK") return setServerError(true);
```

Comment: well now it stays false for some reason I don't why

Comment: Where are you checking for its value?

Comment: console and i have i condition to render this message but this show false always {serverError === true ? (
                <p className="text-center">Email already Exists</p>
              ) : (
                <p className="text-center">false</p>
              )}

Comment: Can you check if block under this condition executes `if (res.statusText != "OK")` executes?

Comment: if (res!='OK') {
      setServerError(true)
      console.log(serverError)
    }   // This still gives false on the log

Comment: Are you sure that the console.log statements before `localStorage.setItem("token", res.headers["x-auth-token"]);` are not executing? I think the IF block never executes.

Comment: yeah because jwt key was stored in the memory when I checked it

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

`if (!res.statusText === "OK")`

You have to use `!==` or `!=` ( first one is equality check with datatype and second one is equality check. So the condition will be like:

```
if (res.statusText != "OK")
{
  return setServerError(true);
}
```

Comment: well now it stays false for some reason I don't why

Comment: Still facing issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have error here

```
if (!res.statusText === "OK")
```

As you have defined a NOT operator before the variable it treats the variable to Boolean value that means `Boolean === String` => `false` always

Just keep

```
if (res.statusText === "OK")
```

And in case you want to check if there is value or not use in response.

```
if (res?.statusText === "OK")
```